# How can I include or exclude a value in range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to take a value, located in list.index()+1 position in order to use in a for range

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,2,6]

indexar = [i for i, n in enumerate(li) if n == 3]

for i in li[0:indexar[0]]:
  print(i)
```

I would like to get:

```
1
2
```

I've tried  indexar[0]-1 but this doesn't work.

```
for i in li[0:indexar[0]-1]:
  print(i)
```

How can I get this values without coding another for or some extra variables in order to add that 2?

Comment: why do you think that you can't use `indexar[0]+2` in Python? Did you try?

Comment: you need number `3` instead of string "3"` in `if n == "3"`

Comment: if you need index of first `3` on list then you can use `li.index(3)` and `for i in li[0:li.index(3)]`

Comment: you have to use `]` instead of `)` at the end of line `for i in li[ 0:indexar[0] ]:` and it will work as you expect.

Comment: I can solve this creating endRange= li.index(3)+1 but I'm asking if there is something to exclude a value in a for range()

Comment: you can use `li.index(3)+1` in `range(li.index(3)+1)` and `list[:li.index(3)+1]` , you don't have to create variable.

Comment: what means "doesn't work." ? Do you get error ? Then add full error in question. Text "doesn't work." is useless information.

Comment: code with `indexar[0]-1` works for me - but you have to change string `"3"` to integer `3` in `if n == "3"` . If you use string `"3"` then `indexar` is empty and you can't get `[0]` from empty list. And it gives error `"IndexError: list index out of range"`. So you have problem in different place then you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude a number in the list, use `continue` in the for loop

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,2,6]
for i in li:
    if i == 3: 
       continue
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,2,6]
end = 2

for i in range(0, end):
  print(li[i])
```

Comment: I can't define the end of the range as 2 because it depends of indexar content, so it must be a variable

Comment: its best to provide details about your answer.